# DNS server in use is not that as specified in TCP/IPv4 properties. Why? [Windows 7]

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, router

I have been able to work around my issue, so I am not looking for a solution, but I am looking for an answer as to why I am seeing the behaviour as described here:

**Context:** I'm developing an application that uses a software component to relay email messages out, using a local SMTP server component. I'm on a Windows 7 dev machine on a residential broadband connection behind a Virgin Media Super Hub router.

The component requires that I specify a DNS address for domain name resolution. Initially, I used the DNS server address as specified in my TCP/IPv4 connection properties. My attempts to relay email failed with a time out at domain name resolution.

[image]

I used cmd window "`nslookup www.google.com`". This failed with a time out:

[image]

So I used "`ipconfig/all`" to check name servers again. The name server is reported as being at address 192.168.0.1

[image]

At this point my internet connection is working as normal, so I change my TCP/IPv4 connection properties to "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain an DNS server address automatically".

Following this, I test SMTP relay, and it works.

I use "`ipconfig/all`" again, and find that my name servers are now reported as:

194.168.4.100
194.168.8.100

Now I change my TCP/IPv4 connection properties back to the fixed settings as before.

Providing that I continue to specify 194.168.4.100 as the name servers in my SMTP relaying application, everything works, despite Windows being configured to use 192.168.0.1.

I don't like not understanding why:

1. I'm unable to check the DNS server that is in use using standard cmd methods.
2. Why windows appears to be using a different DNS server address to that which is configured.

Could anyone address the above points, and also answer my question here:

1. Is it possible that my router is translating DNS addresses for some types of query, but not for others?

Any light that can be shed here is appreciated!

Comment: the answer to question 1 is the standard tools were working just fine and were reporting acurately and 2 it was not using different dns server to return results it was just using misconfigured dns settings . The only case were this is not true is if you have either a virus or you modified you hosts file.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your home network router. Oh, and consider using software components which don't suck. Your application will be better. :)

Comment: Given that nslookup also failed, I won't be blaming the software components on this occasion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're encountering an odd quirk with their DNS setup.

`194.168.4.100` and `194.168.8.100` appear to be ISP DNS servers. `208.67.222.222` is an OpenDNS server, and `192.168.0.1` is your router's DNS (which is probably using one of the former for DNS resolution).

So, I'm concluding that your router's DNS is either non-existent or not functioning properly. However ...when you're using DHCP, your "automatic" settings switch to ISP-assigned settings rather than the router settings. So...probably just a quirk on how the network it set up.

Comment: Seems to be the consensus. Good to hear that it's most likely a fault and not another massive gap in my networking knowledge!